# How can I tell javascript to execute after max-width

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate, css

I want to execute below JavaScript only if width is set to 600px or above. How can I put max-width condition?

```
$(function() {

   $('#nav li a').bind('click',function(event){
       var $anchor = $(this);

            $('html, body').stop().animate({
                scrollTop: $($anchor.attr('href')).offset().top
            }, 1500,'easeInOutExpo');               

                event.preventDefault();
        });
});
```

Comment: Are you talking about the viewport width?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the viewport width, you'd do something like this inside the click callback.

```
if ($(window).width() < 600) {
    return;
}
```